# Native crashes on abort in developer console with Oreo (8.1)

Tags: android, native

In the developer console I get more and more a native crash in abort. This occurs ONLY for android 8.1 device!
Is anybody aware of a regression? Here is the backtrace:

```
   #00  pc 000000000001da4c  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+112)
   #01  pc 0000000000007f7c  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+312) 
   #02  pc 000000000006cff8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::EglManager::createSurface(ANativeWindow*, bool)+324) 
   #03  pc 000000000006ad14  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::OpenGLPipeline::setSurface(android::Surface*, android::uirenderer::renderthread::SwapBehavior, android::uirenderer::renderthread::ColorMode)+72) 
   #04  pc 00000000000679ec  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::setSurface(android::Surface*)+144) 
   #05  pc 00000000000703bc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::Bridge_initialize(android::uirenderer::renderthread::initializeArgs*)+16) 
   #06  pc 00000000000726c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::MethodInvokeRenderTask::run()+24) 
   #07  pc 00000000000738d8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+336) 
   #08  pc 0000000000011504  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+264) 
   #09  pc 00000000000a9830  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140) 
   #10  pc 0000000000069c94  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36) 
   #11  pc 000000000001eeec  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

UPDATE:
I guess the issue can be solved only by Google themselves :( Issue is tracked here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70259031

In the meantime, could someone already reproduce the issue or at least explain when the issue occurs? This would help to find a workaround!

Comment: Hi. I have the same issues on my apps, did you find any solution?

Comment: Great to hear, I'm not the only one ;) No, no solution and issue is still occuring :(

Comment: JB Cha I started a bounty, hopefully we would get an answer :)

Comment: we're going to need a lot more information to be able to help.

Comment: What are the missing information? I should be able to provide them as I have the exact same issue

Comment: @ThomasThomas have you found anything? Or still facing this issue?

Comment: I still have this issue in the reports.

Comment: Fortunately I'm not the only one. I was going to get mad because of this crash report, glad it's not a problem of my code.

Comment: @fillobotto I was thinking the same at the beginning. Unfortunately it does not seem to be a priority for Google :(

Comment: Seriously, what's wrong with Google? Seems like there are tons of bugs they don't want to fix.

Comment: are there any news about that?

Comment: @Nakamoto no, no news and no clue when Google will fix this. And I still don't know how to reproduce the issue.
According to this comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70259031#comment30 issue could be due to too many open files. But that's not the case for me.

Comment: We have the same problem

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: Issue still appears (January 7, 2020)

Answer (score 4):

that a `Surface` is being used hints for [OpenGL ES](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl) and [GLSurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView) - which extends `View`.

a possible workaround might be to disable hardware acceleration for the views, which cause it to crash on Android `8.1` and `9.0` (as `libhwui.so` hints for) - because even if it gets fixed, any device not updated will still keep crashing. this can be done per `View` (see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel)):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
    mSurface.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

of course, this would result in sub-optimal performance; but still better than a crash.

Comment: Hii, where i need to add this line

Answer (score 4):

Check out this answer:

[tgkill - native error on Android 8.0 Samsung S8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360227/tgkill-native-error-on-android-8-0-samsung-s8)

It seems it might be related to Samsung S8 and Samsung S8+.

Basically, if you have an edit text in a dialog or dialog fragment, highlight the text and then close the dialog (or do an orientation change) this crash will occur.

To resolve the issue, I had to turn off hardwareAcceleration on the offending activities - this can be done in the manifest and will cause the activity to lag a bit.

```
   <activity android:name=".activities.CarDamageActivity"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
```

To help prevent the lag on OTHER devices, one can check the device model and if it is NOT a S8 or S8+, turn ON the hardware acceleration.

```
    String phoneMake =  Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String phoneModel =  Build.MODEL.toUpperCase();
    if (!(phoneMake.equalsIgnoreCase("samsung") && (phoneModel.startsWith("SM-G950")
            ||  phoneModel.startsWith("SM-G955")))) {
        window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
    }
```

Comment: Disabling HW acceleration for the whole `Activity` is pointless, when it only affects a `Surface`.

Comment: I am getting this for instrumentation-tests on official `API 28` Emulator (Android 9.0). And exactly after fixing `Fragment` dialog leak (by dismissing androidx `Dialog` in `onPause` callback). But I can not confirm anything Samsung related.