# Native Crash tgkill+8 for MediaPlayer (Samsung Oreo 8.0)

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer, android-8.0-oreo

We are seeing a weird `tgkill` native crash for all kinds of Samsung devices with Android Oreo 8.0.

[image: Play Store Console Screenshot]

```
#00  pc 000000000006b818  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
#01  pc 000000000001df10  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+88)
#02  pc 0000000000007f44  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+304)
#03  pc 0000000000015a94  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper4wakeEv+192)
#04  pc 0000000000695368  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Binder.restoreCallingIdentity [DEDUPED]+152)
#05  pc 00000000010b04b4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.MessageQueue.quit+276)
#06  pc 00000000010aaff4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.quitSafely+68)
#07  pc 0000000000e304c8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaPlayer$4.run+456)
#08  pc 0000000001042b60  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+80)
#09  pc 00000000010a9d00  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1184)
#10  pc 000000000104521c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.HandlerThread.run+620)
#11  pc 0000000000507d84  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
#12  pc 00000000000d82f4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+200)
#13  pc 00000000004309cc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+104)
#14  pc 0000000000431b58  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+432)
#15  pc 0000000000458038  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+1140)
#16  pc 0000000000068194  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
#17  pc 000000000001f664  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

We are using the MediaPlayer, so maybe this makes sense: `android.media.MediaPlayer$4.run+456`

The thing is, we have no idea how to debug it. Any ideas on what this crash is really about?

(Trying to get a Samsung with 8.0 in the meantime)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is relevant: 
[tgkill - native error on Android 8.0 Samsung S8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360227/tgkill-native-error-on-android-8-0-samsung-s8)

Basically its EditText messing up on rotate for android 8.