# Android App Crash for 8.1

Tags: android

App is running fine on api versions below 27 , but giving following error on emualtor:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
08-03 14:34:38.356 22642-22673/org.hisp.dhis.android.trackercapture_dev A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 22673 (RenderThread), pid 22642 (ckercapture_dev)
08-03 14:34:38.554 24823-24823/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
08-03 14:34:38.555 1534-1534/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 22642
08-03 14:34:38.556 24823-24823/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 22642 (target tid = 22673)
08-03 14:34:38.557 24823-24823/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-03 14:34:38.558 24823-24823/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:8.1.0/OSM1.180201.021/4741582:userdebug/dev-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'x86'
08-03 14:34:38.559 24823-24823/? A/DEBUG: pid: 22642, tid: 22673, name: RenderThread  >>> org.hisp.dhis.android.trackercapture_dev <<<
    signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
08-03 14:34:38.563 24823-24823/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'Failed to create EGLSurface for window 0xc6abc008, eglErr = EGL_BAD_ALLOC'
08-03 14:34:38.565 24823-24823/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 00005872  ecx 00005891  edx 00000006
        esi 00000000  edi 00005872
08-03 14:34:38.566 24823-24823/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 0000006b  xss 0000002b
        eip f3921af0  ebp efa02220  esp d2f7f168  flags 00000296
08-03 14:34:38.602 24823-24823/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 00000af0  [vdso:f3921000] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
        #01 pc 0001edf8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
        #02 pc 0001f073  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+115)
        #03 pc 00006ab4  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+292)
        #04 pc 0004a021  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::EglManager::createSurface(ANativeWindow*, bool)+321)
        #05 pc 000475ad  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::OpenGLPipeline::setSurface(android::Surface*, android::uirenderer::renderthread::SwapBehavior, android::uirenderer::renderthread::ColorMode)+93)
        #06 pc 00043e0e  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::setSurface(android::Surface*)+158)
        #07 pc 000440d3  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::initialize(android::Surface*)+35)
        #08 pc 0004d795  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::Bridge_initialize(android::uirenderer::renderthread::initializeArgs*)+37)
        #09 pc 00050452  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::MethodInvokeRenderTask::run()+34)
        #10 pc 00051a2a  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+442)
        #11 pc 00010426  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+326)
08-03 14:34:38.603 24823-24823/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0007870b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+171)
        #13 pc 0000fd86  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+246)
        #14 pc 00071445  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53)
        #15 pc 000205db  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+75)
        #16 pc 0001ec16  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
```

There are some more errors about memory leak , can share if this is not enough

Comment: share more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457748/native-crashes-on-abort-in-developer-console-with-oreo-8-1