# libhwui.so：Failed to create EGLSurface for window 0xb670b008, eglErr = EGL_BAD_ALLOC

Tags: android

My application does not use GL layout, but the number of problems with libhwui is high.

I found commonality in these bugs.When the app is switching between the foreground and background，The Surface will be recreated

```
    05-19 23:57:07.012 30721 30721 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/dipper/dipper:9/PKQ1.180729.001/V10.3.2.0.PEACNXM:user/release-keys'
    05-19 23:57:07.012 30721 30721 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
    05-19 23:57:07.012 30721 30721 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
    05-19 23:57:07.012 30721 30721 F DEBUG   : pid: 11899, tid: 12223, name: RenderThread  >>> com.sankuai.meituan <<<
    05-19 23:57:07.012 30721 30721 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code 0 (SI_USER), fault addr --------
    05-19 23:57:07.012 30721 30721 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'Failed to create EGLSurface for window 0xb670b008, eglErr = EGL_BAD_ALLOC'
    05-19 23:57:07.012 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     r0  00000000  r1  00002fbf  r2  00000006  r3  00000008
    05-19 23:57:07.012 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     r4  00002e7b  r5  00002fbf  r6  b82ff414  r7  0000010c
    05-19 23:57:07.012 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     r8  00000000  r9  ba903450  r10 ba903444  r11 ba903428
    05-19 23:57:07.013 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     ip  b82ff3b0  sp  b82ff400  lr  e956c139  pc  e9563e56
    05-19 23:57:07.267 30721 30721 F DEBUG   : 
    05-19 23:57:07.267 30721 30721 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
    05-19 23:57:07.268 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0001ce56  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+58)
    05-19 23:57:07.268 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00006ccd  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+156)
    05-19 23:57:07.268 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00363215  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::EglManager::createSurface(ANativeWindow*, bool)+212)
    05-19 23:57:07.268 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0035f2f7  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::setSurface(android::Surface*, android::uirenderer::renderthread::SwapBehavior, android::uirenderer::renderthread::ColorMode)+46)
    05-19 23:57:07.268 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00361aeb  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::setSurface(android::sp<android::Surface>&&)+62)
    05-19 23:57:07.268 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 000a18f3  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread11RenderProxy10initializeERKNS2_2spINS2_7SurfaceEEEE3$_6NS_9allocatorISB_EEFvvEEclEv$64c930c5b4139b4fd99ae4f62fbd45a8+12)
    05-19 23:57:07.268 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 0032b2ff  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+122)
    05-19 23:57:07.268 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 000a3243  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+178)
    05-19 23:57:07.268 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 0000c113  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+166)
    05-19 23:57:07.268 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 000637f5  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
    05-19 23:57:07.268 30721 30721 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 0001e019  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+24)
```

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/48457748/981937